# How to Debug Jquery Mobile Button Style Not Working?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I've somehow messed up the button styling for input/button elements. Anchor tags work just fine. Here's a picture:

[image]

My "reduced repro" is pretty basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
    <script src="/static/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.ui.touch-punch-2013.8.30.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/underscore-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/json2-2013.5.26.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/backbone-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="main-content">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      ...
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Anchor</a>
        <form>
          <button>Button</button>
          <input type="button" value="Input">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The DOM after rendering:

```
  <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Anchor</span></span></a>
    <form>
      <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Button</span></button>
      <input type="button" value="Input" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    </form>
  </div>
```

A few questions:

1. Anyone recognize what would cause this?
2. Any tips/pointers on how to debug? JQM injects a lot of html into the page to dynamically enhance the display of widgets. I'd like to set a breakpoint on whatever should be wrapping the input/button elements but I don't know where to start. With css it's pretty easy to see when a rule doesn't fire. But with this framework I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Buttons should have `.ui-btn` it looks missing here, in addition to other classes such as `.ui-btn-up-c` etc. maybe jquery-ui is conflicting with JQM.

Comment: @Omar Yes! Thank you. If I comment out the jquery-ui include or move it above the jquery-mobile include then it displays correctly. Was this an educated guess or do you know why? If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks again.

Comment: %99.99 guess ;) if you load jquery-ui before JQM, the problem will vanish. But the question is, why do you need jQ-ui while JQM has everything yiu need?

Comment: I am transitioning a site to JQM and some existing widgets depend on jquery ui.